# Cannot get my file to display through Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having problems with my node server. I'm trying to gather data from my coffees.js file which is in a routes folder by linking it to my server.js file. Both my server.js file and routes folder containg the coffees.js file are in my nodeservers folder. When I run the server.js (which is probably the problem as I think it is coded wrong) I get the following error:

Server running at http-00000000-:8080/
   Listening on port 8080...

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1042:14)
at listen (net.js:1064:10)
at Server.listen (net.js:1138:5)
at Function.app.listen (/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:533:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/nodeservers/simpleserver.js:19:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
[ec2-user@ip-10-74-151-139 nodeservers]$ ^C                                                                                                                                                     
[ec2-user@ip-10-74-151-139 nodeservers]$
```

My simpleserver.js file looks like this:

```
// Load the http module to create an http server.
var http = require('http');

// Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
response.end("Hello World\n");
});
// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8080);
// Put a friendly message on the terminal
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/");

var express = require('express'),
coffees = require('./routes/coffees');
var app = express();
app.get('/coffees', coffees.findAll);
app.get('/coffees/:id', coffees.findById);
app.listen(8080);
console.log('Listening on port 8080...');
```

Anyone able to tell me whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove either

`server.listen(8080)` or `app.listen(8080)`.

I think you want to use express, so remove the first.